# On the definition of a semiring of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In modern terms, $\mathcal{S}$ is a semiring means that

1. $A, B \in \mathcal{S} \implies A B \in \mathcal{S}$
2. $A, B \in \mathcal{S} \implies A \setminus B = \coprod_{i = 1}^{n} C_i \text{ for some } (C_i)_{1 \dots n} \in \mathcal{S}$

My quetion is, if we replace condition 2 with
$$
\forall A, B \in \mathcal{S}. \exists (C_i)_{1 \dots } \in \mathcal{S}. A \setminus B = \coprod_{i = 1}^{\infty} C_i.,
$$

then will it have any significant impact on the results deduced from the original version in measure theory?